# minko - cannot compile dev branch

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, segmentation-fault, minko

I am trying to compile the dev branch of [minko](http://minko.io)
The biggest API change (from the master branch) is the math API.

The very few examples that compile for linux64 don't run (example assimp opens a window and closes immediately). Nevertheless, I managed to modify my code to use the new API and it compiles fine, however on launch it also crashes with a segmentation fault at :

```
sceneMan->assets()->loader()->load();
```

Any idea what might be wrong ? (Same asset folder works perfectly with non dev branch).

Answer (score 0):

This could be a lot of things, from the file loader to the parsers. Could you try to handle the error signal from the loader to see what the error could be ?